# String pointer manipulation

Tags: c++, string

I have this assignment at school. A string pointer is passed to the function and returns 2 const strings to a different functions.
The 2 new strings divide the original string into 2 parts based on a space.
Example:
Input

```
str = 05/12 Hello
```

Desired output

```
key = 05/12  
satData = Hello
```

This is the code I wrote but its giving me errors. Please help

```
void RBapp::processInsert(string &str)
{
  string *key = new string();
  string *satData = new string();
  int i = 0, j =0;
  while(str[i]!=" ")
  {
    key[j] = str[i];
    i++;
    j++;
  }
  j = 0;
  while(str[i]!='\0')
  {
    satData[j] = str[i];
    i++;
    j++;
  }
  myRBT.rbInsert(key, satData);
}
```

Comment: Your code is not [C] so please do not tag it as such.

Comment: Why tag this [c] when it's clearly C++?  *"giving me errors"* - what errors?  Compile time or runtime?  What input are you giving it, and what output is it producing?  What did you expect?  What don't you understand about where it started to go wrong?

Comment: Do you really need to use string pointers here? Also why are you expecting a `std::string` to be NULL terminated?

Comment: Re the code: you can't do `while(str[i]!=" ")  { key[j] = str[i];`... firstly, `str[i]` is a `char` so should be compared to `' '` (single quotes); secondly, `key[j]` doesn't exist for `j > 0` - you should be using `*key += str[i]`.  Same for `*satData += str[i]`.  (Or - better, as Christopher suggests below - make `key` and `satData` strings, not pointers to `string`s.

Comment: @tadman: as of C++11, `std::string`s are guaranteed NUL terminated.

Comment: Yes about the pointers: it tries to index characters when it is actually indexing strings inside a buffer, but ones with with only one string.

Comment: Why not use a stringstream?

Comment: Why are you using `new` at all? Why not just `string key; string satData;`?

Answer (score 2):

Using stringstream

```
void RBapp::processInsert(const std::string &str)
{
  std::stringstream ss(str);

  std::string key;
  std::string satData;

  ss >> key;
  ss >> satData;

 myRBT.rbInsert(key, satData);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your program is subject to undefined behavior since you are accessing memory that is not valid.

When you use:

```
string *key = new string();
string *satData = new string();
```

You have two pointers that point to empty strings.

```
key[j] = str[i];
```

is wrong if `j > 0` since that points to invalid memory.

Based on the description of what you are trying to do, what you need is something along the lines of:

```
void RBapp::processInsert(string &str)
{
   // There is no need to use new string.
   // Just use two string objects.
   string key;
   string satData;

   int i = 0;
   while(str[i]!=" ")
   {
      // Add the character to key
      key.push_back(str[i]);
      i++;
   }

   // Increment i here if you want the space to be excluded from
   // satData. If you want to include the space character in satData,
   // then, there is no need to increment i
   ++i;

   while(str[i]!='\0')
   {
      // Add the character to satData
      satData.push_back(str[i]);
      i++;
   }
   myRBT.rbInsert(key, satData);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You say you receive a string pointer - what I see is you receive a `string`.  In C++ you would try to avoid hand-written loops as much as possible - [`std::string`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/) has a lot of stuff you need.

```
void process(const string &str) {

    auto firstSpace = str.find_first_of(' ');
    auto key = str.substr(0, firstSpace);
    auto value = str.substr(firstSpace, string::npos);

    myRBT.rbInsert(key, value);
}
```